# 2D array and an out of bounds exception

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The last for loop will compile but it won't run. It says that array index out of bounds exception:17. I just want to add a ColorRectangles (subclass of ColorShape) to the 1-8 columns in the 17'th row

```
private ColorShape[][] _tiles; 

public GamePanel()
{
   _tiles = new ColorShape[8][17];

  for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){
          for(int j=0; j<8;j++){
              _tiles[j][i] = null;
          }
     }

  for (int j=0; j<8;j++){
            _tiles[j][17] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);

     }
}
```

Comment: It should be: `_tiles[j][16]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array size is 17.  Arrays are zero-indexed.  This means your maximum array index for your second dimension is actually 16, not 17.

Either change your reference to tiles to:

```
_tiles[j][16] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

OR make your _tiles array bigger like so:

```
_tiles = new ColorShape[8][18];
```

Either will fix this problem.

May I also suggest that your game panel object accept 2 dimensions, width and height.  This makes your class more useable should you decide to use it again, or change its dimensions.  Avoid hardcoding values whenever appropriate.  Here it would be most appropriate.

Here's a rewrite for you:

```
private ColorShape[][] _tiles; 

public GamePanel(int width, int height)
{
   _tiles = new ColorShape[width][height];

   for (int i = 0; i<height; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<width;j++){
          _tiles[j][i] = null;
      }
   }

  for (int j=0; j<width;j++){
        _tiles[j][tiles[j].length-1] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);

 }
}
```

And here's how you would use it in your case:

```
GamePanel panel = new GamePanel(8, 17);
```

But you can always easily change your panels dimensions now!

```
GamePanel panel = new GamePanel(100,100);
```

Nifty huh?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
_tiles[j][17] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

17 is not a valid index for your array since you sized it as `[8][17]`. Indices are from `0...length - 1`, so in your case, up to 16. This is because arrays in Java (and any reasonable programming language) are [zero-indexed](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). Thus, replace with

```
_tiles[j][16] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

and at least you won't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

> I just want to add a ColorRectangles (subclass of ColorShape) to the 1-8 columns in the 17'th row

See, in a zero-based indexing scheme, the 17th row *is* the row with index 16.

The first row corresponds to that with index 0. The second row corresponds to that with index 1. Etc. In general, the `nth` row corresponds to that with index `n - 1` and a row with index `n` is actually the `(n + 1)th` row (assuming `0 <= n < length - 1`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
_tiles[j][17] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

You should have this instead (note that arrays are zero-indexed, so 17th column is at index 16):

```
_tiles[j][16] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, indexing starts from zero (0);

```
 private ColorShape[][] _tiles; 

 public GamePanel()
 {
    _tiles = new ColorShape[8][18]; // new dim is 18 so last index is 17

   for (int i = 0; i<18; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<8;j++){
               _tiles[j][i] = null;
           }
      }

   for (int j=0; j<8;j++){
             _tiles[j][17] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK); //17 was out of bounds

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of your array is `[8][17]` but the indexes go from `[0]` to `[16]`.
Therefor replace

```
_tiles[j][17] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

with

```
_tiles[j][16] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your array with 8 fields in x range and 17 fields in y range in your code:

```
 _tiles = new ColorShape[8][17];
```

Because you start counting from zero in the IT, the range is from zero to sixteen (`0-16`). 
So if you want the last field of the array, you have to use the field 16 (`_tiles[j][16]`).

The code should be:

```
_tiles[j][16] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);
```

The whole thing is called [zero-based-numbering/index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`JLS` (Array Access)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) - `All arrays are 0-origin. An array with length n can be indexed by the integers 0 to n-1.`

So if you initialize an array like you did `_tiles = new ColorShape[8][17];`. In order to access you need to do it by `0 to 7` and `0 to 16`.

Now, with `_tiles[j][17] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);` you are trying to access something with is outside the array you have initialized and therefore you get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a bug for the first loop.
Instead of
`for (int i = 0; i<16; i++)`
it should be 
`for (int i = 0; i<17; i++)`

Arrays are zero-indexed meaning the starting index is 0 up to length-1.

So, in your case, it is up to 16.

For your second loop, it should be

`_tiles[j][16] = new ColorRectangle(Color.BLACK);`